# To develop a split view in android

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I would like to implement a split view like in facebook in my app.
The functionality when I click a button another activity comes and that should work exactly like in facebook
How can I develop this can anyone help me

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) by Jeremy Feinstein